# Count the number of calculations in a loop

Tags: r

I have a large dataset for a nested loop. I was able to count the time the computer takes to finish the loop. I'm also curious about the number of calculations made in the loop. Is there a simple way (like system.time function to calculate the time used) to count the total number of calculations made in the whole loop?

Below is the sample data

```
test = data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), s= c(0.4,0.3,0.3), j1 = c(0.3,0.22,0.15), j2 = c(0.11,0.3,0.2))
```

Below is the loop:

```
j = 1
k = 1

firstsum = 0
tm1 <- system.time(
  while (j <= nrow(test)){
    while (k <= nrow(test)){
      if (k != j) {
        for (i in 3:4){
          normindator = 0
          denominator = 0

          normindator = normindator + (test[j,i] * test[k, i])
          denominator = denominator + test[j, i] * test[j, i]
          firstsum = firstsum + normindator/denominator * test[k, 2]

        }
      }
      k = k + 1
    }
    secondsum = 0
    secondsum = secondsum + firstsum * test[j,2]
    j = j + 1
    k = 1
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just specify it alone. Check that I put it correctly, but you can do something like this even if it is not nice.

```
test = data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3), s= c(0.4,0.3,0.3), j1 = c(0.3,0.22,0.15), j2 = c(0.11,0.3,0.2))

j = 1
k = 1
count <- 0
firstsum = 0
tm1 <- system.time(
  while (j <= nrow(test)){
    count <- count + 1
    while (k <= nrow(test)){
      if (k != j) {
        for (i in 3:4){
          normindator = 0
          denominator = 0

          normindator = normindator + (test[j,i] * test[k, i])
          denominator = denominator + test[j, i] * test[j, i]
          firstsum = firstsum + normindator/denominator * test[k, 2]
          count<- count + 1
        }
      }
      else{count<- count +1 }
      k = k + 1
    }
    secondsum = 0
    secondsum = secondsum + firstsum * test[j,2]
    j = j + 1
    k = 1
    count <- count +1
  }
)
tm1
count
# > tm1
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.02    0.00    0.02 
# > count
# [1] 21
```

I know it is not a nice way, but it is fast to check your purpose.
If you want to know specifically how much of each one, just put a different counter variable to each loop. Cheers !